# How to parse operations in c?

Tags: c

I decided to refresh my C by wring a simple little program.  I tried to read in from a file "myfile.txt", apply operations and print to stdout. The file contains one line:

```
2 + 3
```

the output I expect is:

```
5
```

but I found this to be much more complicated than I originally expected.  At first I tried using getc() but kept getting segfaults, then I tried fscanf() there is no output from addition to stdin except the print statement that prints:

```
2   1556274040
```

Why is the output 2   1556274040? And is there a better way to try to apply operations read form a file, like some apply() function that I can use?
Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
  int ans, num1, num2;
  char oper;
  FILE *pFile;
  pFile = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
  if (pFile != NULL) {
    fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num1);
    fscanf(pFile, "%c", &oper);
    fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num2);
    printf ("%d %c %d", num1, oper, num2);
    if (oper == '+') {
      ans = num1 + num2;
      printf(ans);
    }
    fclose(pFile);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to allow for whitespace in your `fscanf` format string.

Comment: `fscanf(pFile, " %c", &oper);` note the leading space. That allows for any number of whitespace chars preceding the character (in this case operator) you're after

Comment: A really fun and interesting exersice would be to parse `infix` notation. It will allow you to turn an expression like `1+2*3-4*5` into a tree and correctly calculate its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf(ans);
```

Not a valid syntax to print an `int variable`.
Try this -

```
printf("%d\n",ans);
```

As you ask
you can use [`fgets`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) instead of using `fscanf` to read contents of file but make sure you *check their return*.

Comment: And preferably add a `\n`.

Comment: @Jite   Just did that .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution...

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main() {    
  int ans, num1, num2;    
  char oper;    
  FILE *pFile;

  pFile = fopen("myfile.txt", "r"); // might need to specify binary/text

   if (pFile != NULL) {
     // fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num1); need spaces in format specifier.
     // fscanf(pFile, "%c", &oper);
     // fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num2);
     // one way to solve...

     fscanf(pFile, "%d %c %d", &num1, &oper, &num2);

     fclose(pFile); // stopping some errors
     printf ("%d %c %d = ", num1, oper, num2);
   } // end if
   else    
     puts("fopen returned NULL");

   if (oper == '+') {
     ans = num1 + num2;
     printf("%d",ans);
   } // end if

    return 0;
}  // end main
```